# Secure a Spring boot rest api

Tags: rest, api, security, spring-boot

I have a created spring boot rest api that I intend to call from another application. How can I secure it in such a way that I can only call my api from that application.

I am very new at this so I really don't have any idea how to do it as I am a newbie in spring security.

Thank you for the recommendations.